# Create a new column or create a new table in database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have a dataBase with table `schedule` and many data with this properties like `id` `title` `type` `description` and foreigns keys called `day_id` `event_id`

The `day_id` make a relationship with table `schedule_day` that contains the property `id` and `date`

What's the best design and performance search for this two cases:

1- Keep different tables, a table day and a table schedule with foreign key to day

or

2- Create a column date in schedule table e remove the `shedule_day` table

Comment: without knowing your whole system the answer depends on a lot of other factors.....in general, if the only information that `schedule_day` contains is the id and date, it seems like just adding a date column would be more efficient. It would also result in shorter queries because you won't have to join the two tables every time

Comment: but in case that I have 1 million entries and I want a list of schedule with specific day. I believe that is more efficient a second table that a column. But I can be wrong

Comment: Your second table will have the date. The DBMS will look this up, find the id and then go looking for the ID in the first table. So, no ... if you have the right indexes -- just put a date field on the table. No need for a second one.

Comment: But in case that I have the same date in many schedule, the performance would be better in separate tables? Returning same column information, is redundante, right?

Answer (score 0):

If schedule_day contains only two columns and has no chance to add column in future then it should be replaced by adding one column into schedule table.

In terms of performance, join of two table require time.

Comment: But in case that I have the same date in many schedule, the performance would be better in separate tables? Returning same column information, is redundante, right?

Comment: schedule table contains day_id which represents the date, if same date in many schedule then same day_id in many schedule too. to get the schedules with dates you must join these 2 tables. to keep 2 column into one table, I believe it will not add any value to your design

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan is right, I see your concern about redundancy but it is negligible in this case. Storing the id and storing the date are basically the same here. Now if it was something like the *title* of a book or a *description* that takes up a lot more memory than a date, your concern is valid....